# How can I calculate the total duration between two date/times with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named it_outage that looks like this:

```
office |        start        |         end         | total
------------------------------------------------------------
nyc    | 2014-07-01 20:56:00 | 2014-07-01 22:19:00 | 01:23 |
ewi    | 2014-07-17 17:35:00 | 2014-07-17 18:05:00 | 00:30 |
nyc    | 2014-07-11 03:09:00 | 2014-07-11 03:26:00 | 00:17 |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, basically it just shows when office had downtime and how long it lasted. How do I calculate (add) total time for "nyc" office only? So, I want the output be 01:40 (combined 01:23 + 00:17).

My query looks like this (I'm using Joomla 3.3):

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'office', 'start', 'end', 'total')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__outage'));
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with SQL or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this mySQL with your Joomla db object:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select("office,`start`,`end`,SEC_TO_TIME( SUM((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`end`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start`))) ) AS total_outage");
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__outage'));
$query->group('office');
$db->setQuery($query);
foreach($result= $db->loadObjectList() as $outage) {
    echo $outage->office . "  :  " . $outage->total_outage . '<Br/>';
}
```

Gives this:

```
ewi : 00:30:00
nyc : 01:40:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your Query result to the below code.

```
$i=0;
foreach( $results as $row)
{
 if($i == 0 ){
  $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $row['total']);
 } 

 $arr = explode(':',$row['total']);

 $dt->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$arr[0].'H'));
 $dt->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$arr[1].'M'));
 $i++;  
}
/* Total time */
echo $dt->format('H:i');
```